# How to save ffmpeg stream with datetime

Tags: python, datetime, ffmpeg

I would like to write an output format from a ffmpeg encode line to save the stream in a SD card with date and hour.

To simplify the question I write the following (just ignore the extras):

```
import subprocess, sus, os, datetime, time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def call_command(command):
    subprocess.Popen(command.split('  '))

call_command('ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -y -s qvga -r 24 -i /dev/video0 \
              -vcodec mpeg2video /home/pi/webcam_+%Y/%m/%d_at_%H:%M:%S.mpg')
```

I also tried another solutions like define firstly the filename and call it from the ffmpeg line but it doesen't work.

Comment: *import subprocess, sys, os, datetime, time